# Hyperledger Fabric Docker Compose YAML Error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am new to Hyperledger and am setting up the environment (on my mac) based on information from [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-chaincode-for-java-developers/index.html)

I am using the following YAML file from the page.

```
membersrvc:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
  ports:
    - "7054:7054"
  command: membersrvc
vp0:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
  ports:
    - "7050:7050"
    - "7051:7051"
    - "7053:7053"
  environment:
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
    - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
    - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_ECA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TLSCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=false
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLID=test_vp0
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLSECRET=MwYpmSRjupbT
  links:
    - membersrvc
  command: sh -c "sleep 5; peer node start --peer-chaincodedev"
```

However, when I run docker-compose up (on my mac), I get a whole listing of warnings and error.  Is it normal to get these issues, or is something missing from the YAML file?  A snippet of the output shown below.

```
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.813 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 198 Module 'msp/identity' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.814 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 199 Module 'msp' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.814 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 19a Module 'configvalues/msp' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.814 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 19b Module 'peer/gossip/mcs' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.814 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 19c Module 'gossip/state' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.814 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 19d Module 'gossip/gossip' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.814 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 19e Module 'gossip/service' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.814 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 19f Module 'gossip/election' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.814 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 1a0 Module 'gossip/comm' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.814 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 1a1 Module 'peer/gossip/sa' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.814 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 1a2 Module 'gossip/discovery' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.814 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 1a3 Module 'gossip/pull' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.814 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 1a4 Module 'kvledger.util' logger enabled for log level 'INFO'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.814 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 1a5 Module 'ledgermgmt' logger enabled for log level 'INFO'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.814 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 1a6 Module 'kvledger' logger enabled for log level 'INFO'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.815 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 1a7 Module 'cauthdsl' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.815 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 1a8 Module 'policies' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
vp0_1         | 2017-10-25 22:23:06.815 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 1a9 Module 'grpc' logger enabled for log level 'ERROR'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are harmless debug messages.

However, that article is a bit dated and references use of the now defunct v0.6 release of Hyperledger Fabric. The Hyperledger Fabric team released [version 1.0.0](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/CHANGELOG.md#v100) in July, and we've even pushed out a few patch releases since.

If you'd like to get started using the new and much improved v1.0.0, then I would strongly recommend you start with the [Getting Started tutorials](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html). There is a whole set of [sample apps](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/stable/samples.html) to play with once you have gotten the first couple of tutorials under your belt.

Comment: Thanks @christo4ferris.  Will try to newer version